# What can be done to focus the .mht file to open in iframe? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use the below code but it is not working.

```js
$('li.link').click(open() { 
    var value = $(this).attr('id');
    $container.cycle(id.replace('pager_', '')); 
    window.open(value + ".mht", 'myFrame');
    return false; 
});
```

```html
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="2" src="https://www.example.com" name="myFrame"> </iframe>

<li onclick="open()" id="xyz" class="link">xyz</li>
<li onclick="open()" id="abc" class="link">abc</li>
<li onclick="open()" id="mac" class="link">macro sed</li>
<li onclick="open()" id="asf he" class="link">asf he</li>
```

when I click an item from the list it is displaying a blank window. How do I display the actual .mht file in the iframe. files placed inside the folder where the html is placed. Any solution appreciated.

Comment: I agree with @JesseLi. That way other people who have similar problems will be able to see your answer.

Comment: Jesse answered as suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution using a href sorry to bother you guys..

```html
<ol class="side">

  <li> <a href="http://example.com/" target="myFrame">example.com</a></li>
  <li> <a href="https://w3schools.com/" target="myFrame">w3schools.com</a></li>
  <li> <a href="http://test.com/" target="myFrame">test.com</a></li>

</ol>

<center><iframe allowtransparency="true" id="myiframe" frameBorder="5" src="http://example.com" scrolling="yes" name="myFrame"> </iframe>
</center>
```

For some reason this is not working in snippet but works as html file.
It seems i'm thinking too much.

By this way most file types can be displayed in iframe